# how could the JSONP request response being retrieved as source before it is appended to site as a script element

Tags: web-services, security, cross-domain, jsonp, httprequest

As JSONP requests are created in the following way:

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='url';
script.onLoad=function(){dosomething()};
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

My question is that, is there a w3c standard, cross-browser supported event like onBeforeLoad which in turn let us stop executing downloaded script, in case it is not a well-formed JSONP response, or it is not passing through some predefined scheme validation, or just in case it consists of some harmful code(basic script validation)?
I know of the onBeforeLoad event supported in some browser out there, but focusing on the downloaded script datasource and in any of the reasons stated above, 
it would be extemely useful to have cross-browser access to the loading script source, and due to good reasons, 
the possibility to stop the execution, just before it is started.

For example the above script could be the following:

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.src='url';
script.onBeforeLoad=function(){
       if(json.parseJson(this.dataSource) && 
          json.validateAgainst(schema,this.dataSource))
       {
          return false;
       }
       else{
          return true;
       }
};
//if onBeforeLoad return true, onLoad will not be fired;
script.onLoad=function(){dosomething()};
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I know that JSONP is all about trust in the 3rd party javascript module, hence i sometime wish that if i could validate those modules just before i am using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect whether the JSONP response is more than the JSONP you are expecting, then no, this is not possible.

If you would be able to read the response, you wouldn’t need JSONP in the first place. Because the main reason to use JSONP is to circumvent the restrictions on accessing the response of XHR requests or via DOM due to the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). And the extension of XHR (formerly known as XHR Level 2) that allows cross-origin requests by supporting the CORS specification may not be applicable due to missing support by browsers and/or by servers.

That’s the main security concern with JSONP: You need to trust the server.

Comment: Thanks. You have confirmed my opinion, that is not possible.

Comment: Though it is note solely possible on the clientside yet, it doesn't mean that it wouldn't have been possible to implement this feature through wide support of some onBeforeLoad event browserside, or progressive adoption of the event by the W3C committee.The only way is possible supporting some kind of JSONP validation is the JSONP RPC proxy, which consume some serverside resource.Definitely there is a big demand on this kind of features, especially when you are building some mashups, which depend on some cross-domain JSON resource, which is essential to validate first before taken into account